# Show products from database that are egal or smaller dotay date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to show a list of upcoming products from database in oscommerce admin panel. The problem is that the function show all products that in system not only the products that must come in future. the function is:

```
$products_query_raw = "select pd.products_id, pd.products_name,
p.products_date_available from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p 
where p.products_id = pd.products_id and p.products_date_available != '' and pd.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' 
order by p.products_date_available asc";
```

How to write hear in the function to compare  p.products_date_available <= with the today date?

Comment: Is your question, what function returns today's date? That depends on your RDBMS which you have not specified.

Comment: I am using php and mysql

Comment: In MySQL, the function to return the current date is `CURDATE()`. If you need a timestamp, use `NOW()`.

Comment: and my function must be  p.products_date_available <= CURDATE() ?

Comment: thenk you, I solved it with now()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like OP would like to select all products where the date is in the future. In that case, this query will work

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE date_available > CURDATE()
```